# Call function depends on selected id from database

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript code.

```
<script>
 $( "#show-ID" ).click(function() {...}
</script>
```

I need this ID make dynamic with mysql DB. Like that in PHP from MySQL.

```
$id = $row["id"];
```

I try all what i found on google but i dont have a lot of experience with JS. 
All what I tried, has syntax error ...

Comment: #show-ID is the id of a div not $id.

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. Javascript is a client-side language. Please try to explain better what you like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code. Its a wild guess, but from the little you have posted, I think you're passing variables between php and js.

```
<script>
var div_id = <?php $row["id"] ?>; //im assuming youre getting $row['id'] correctly

var element = document.createElement("div");
element.id = "my_id";
element.innerHTML = div_id 

$( "#" + element.id ).click(function() {...} 
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, but neither the question nor the answer does make any sense

Comment: It doesnt really.. Im just guessing the OP doesnt know the difference between serverside and clientside